What is the Fisher information matrix of the von Mises-Fisher distribution?
Assuming the von Mises-Fisher distribution as
$$f_{p}(\mathbf{x}; \boldsymbol{\mu}, \kappa) = C_{p}(\kappa) \exp \left( {\kappa \boldsymbol{\mu}^\mathsf{T} \mathbf{x} } \right),$$
where $\kappa \ge 0$, $\left \Vert \boldsymbol{\mu} \right \Vert = 1$, and $C_{p}(\kappa)$ is the normalization constant. How can we calculate the Fisher information matrix regarding the parameter $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ given the constraint $\left \Vert \boldsymbol{\mu} \right \Vert = 1$? Since we only have two degrees of freedom in $\boldsymbol{\mu}$, it seems that its Fisher information matrix will not be invertible. So what can we say about the Cramér-Rao Lower Bound (CRLB)?
